# Желать смерти — КОГО или КОМУ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

*Впрочем, у Бельского, как мы выяснили, не было таких веских оснований **желать смерти*** (кого?) ***Грозного***, как, например, у Годунова.

*Перед смертью же он собирался породниться с английской королевой. Получается, что у Нагих были основания **желать смерти*** (кому?) ***родственничку.***
[**Л. Я. Лурье. 22 смерти, 63 версии. Иван Грозный**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hCQK4aUdQEAC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=1c6KFiXAzz&sig=zPPQ45nEsOjvqAXX4z_bzPsZnvo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr9r_RmN_bAhUJxqYKHTKjABM4ChDoAQhLMAo#v=onepage&q=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false)

Подскажите, какой из падежей правильно использовать? Или возможны оба варианта?
Мне "ближе" дательный падеж (кому?).

Answer (score 2):

У глагола ***желать*** два значения:

ЖЕЛАТЬ,  нсв. 1. чего (также с инф. или с придат. дополнит.). Стремиться к чему-л.; **хотеть чего-л**. Ж. славы, успеха, признанья.  2. (св. пожелать). (кому-чему), чего или с инф. **Высказывать пожелания.** Желаю вам всем счастья и благополучия! Желаем вам доброго пути. Желаю здоровья!

**Желать ему (кому?) смерти**  ― это пожелание. **Желать (хотеть) его (кого?) смерти** ― это заинтересованность.

Примеры:

Но причины **желать его смерти** были у многих политических деятелей его времени. [Календарь компромата (2003) // «Вслух о…», 2003.10.24]

Вот тогда я и **стала желать ему смерти**. [Галина Щербакова. Митина любовь (1996)]

Comment: Меня смутило то, что в небольшом контексте (одного и того же автора), практически в идентичных по смыслу предложениях использованы разные падежи. Я не смогла найти в них ни смысловых, ни каких-либо других явных различий.

Comment: Вероятно, эти формы могут заменять друг друга, то есть сближаются по значению.  Но если речь идет о  мотивации совершенного преступления, то   желательно использовать форму, которая точно выражает заинтересованность, например: Подозреваемый мог желать его смерти.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильнее ставить вопрос не "кого?" (в формально-грамматическом смысле он возможен, но на практике не употребляется из-за корявости), а "**чьей**" смерти (в притяжательном смысле). Вариант "**кому**" столь же правилен. Первый случай характерен для контекста рассуждения о мотивах убийства, второй - для выражения крайне враждебного отношения к кому-либо.

Answer (score 0):

> ... желать смерти (кого? чьей?) Грозного>

Здесь всё правильно, но во второй цитате вопрос идёт от глагола:

*... смерти желать (кому?) родственничку*.

Варианты равноценны, смысловая разница отсутствует.

Comment: Нет-нет,  Вы ошибаетесь: во втором предложении (из одного цитируемого отрывка книги, в "одном поле") тоже сначала — глагол: _...основания желать смерти родственничку._

Comment: Порядок не имеет значения. Не цитата, а пересказ.